# need some explanation on this simple c code

Tags: c

New programer here.Im stuck to a really simple code.I have a problem figuering out how this prime number code works. How does this exactly work? I mean the inserted for(2nd one) gives me trouble. Lets say the i is 4 (since its not prime), so j is 4 now as well. i/2 is 2 so j isnt smaller than i/2. How is prime going from 1 to 0 since that is false? pls help me

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int i, j, prime;
    
    for (i=2; i<1000; i++) {
        
        prime=1;
        for(j=2; j<= i/2; j++)
          if(!(i%j)) prime=0;
        if (prime) printf("%d is prime.\n", i);
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First please learn the differences between C and C++. They are two very different languages, so please don't tag both.

Comment: Why would `j` ever go up to `4` for `i=4`? `j` goes up to `2` only.

Comment: `for (j = 2; j <= i / 2; ...)`. `j` is initialized to `2`. The loop iterates once (because `2 <= 4 / 2` is true). `2 % 2` is zero which is the same as false, condition is negated to true, and `prime` is set to "false".

Comment: `prime` is a *flag* so that after the loop ends the code knows there was a divisor, i.e. the number isn't prime. If the number `i` isn't prime then for some divisor `j`  the remainder of `i%j` is `0` which is considered to be false.

Comment: In your first (and only) execution of the inner loop `j` will be `2` and `i%j` == `4/2` which evaluates to `0`.

Comment: you should use a debugger to understand what the code does.

Comment: It's only necessary to check divisors up to the square root of `i`, not half of `i`.

Comment: ...for which the stopping conditional `j <= i / j` can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Let understand your code line by line

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int i, j, prime;
    
    for (i=2; i<1000; i++) {
        
        prime=1;
        for(j=2; j<= i/2; j++)
          if(!(i%j)) prime=0;
        if (prime) printf("%d is prime.\n", i);
        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

`int i, j, prime;`  it declares the variables

here `prime` is used as a flag. Its value is initially set as `1` in outer loop.`1` means true, `0` means false.

- `if(1) {stmt}` => stmt will execute
- `if(0) {stmt}` => stmt will NOT execute

Now lets take i=11, and first look at the `inner for loop`

```
        for(j=2; j<= i/2; j++)
        {    
              if(!(i%j)) prime=0;
        }
```

This loop will iterate from j=2 to j<=(11/2) i.e.  j<=5 (round off).

Now condition, take j=2,3,4,5 then `i%j= 11%j` gives a non-zero number (as 11 is not divisible by j=2,3,4,5) so `(i%j) is true` => `!(i%j)` is False , thus `prime=0 stmt will not be executed.`

COming out of  inner loop we get the line

```
if (prime) printf("%d is prime.\n", i);
```

It says has two cases:

- if prime == 0 , condition is false, so if stmt will NOT execute.
- if prime == 1 , condition is true, so if stmt will execute.

In `if(!(i%j)) {prime=0;}` the stmt is NOT executed as we discuss above, that's why prime=1 remain only.

Hence it will print the `if (prime) printf("%d is prime.\n", i);` stmt.

And since `11 is prime number`, so our result is also correct.

Now, you can think of iterating `i` as variable , think of same logic.